# WebView in XML not working with Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, webview

I am new to android and cannot find a solution online. I have a navigation drawer that leads to the fragment 'RecentNews', which is related to it's XML 'fragment_recent_news'. I have a WebView (webview) setup in the XML, and have set up the fragment so that it should load a page, but it does not. What am I doing incorrectly? I am unsure if the way to properly do this has changed in the past year because nothing online has worked. Thanks

fragment_recent_news(xml):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness.RecentNews">


<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

RecentNews:

```
package com.hardingsoftware.hrcfitness;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;



public class RecentNews extends Fragment {

WebView webView;




public RecentNews() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recent_news, container, false);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    myWebView.loadUrl("www.hrcfitness.com/recent-news/");
    return rootView;

}


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

}

EDIT: I have the page loading now, however I now have another issue, where the webview seems to ignore the relative layout and part of it is lying under the main bar.

Comment: Have you double checked your manifest permissions?  IE: Declared `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: CzarMatt my manifest permissions do include that line.

Comment: Mike M. When I add that it begins to load, but gets stuck on the websites loading screen. The website works perfectly on any other device.

Comment: Okay, I got the website to load by enabling javascript but there is a new problem- the top bit of the webview loads under my bar at the top of the screen, as though it is ignoring the relative layout guidelines.